# Double data type not returning desired output in java

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

In Java, for the following code

```
Double d = 2.0-1.1;
System.out.println(d);
```

The result is

```
0.8999999999999999
```

If the program is dealing with sensitive information such as precentile/money or cents how do I solve this problem?

I also tried the following piece of code:

```
new BigDecimal(d)
```

which outputs

```
0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

What should I do to get 0.90 for the above case?

Comment: A better duplicate could be [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) which is a particular concern of the op.

Comment: @GregHewgill Could you add the post mentioned above as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `double` cannot accurately represent the result of 2 - 1.11, the precision has already been lost by the time the constructor is used.Therefore you need to chain BigDecimal using the [String based constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String))

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("2").subtract(new BigDecimal("1.1"));
```

The Standard Reference is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) 
A more digestable read: [Floating Point Numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/)

Comment: Do you mind editing the duplicate list to include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency? I think this question may be helpful to future readers.